# Arranging nodes-edges for 'good looking' graph layout

Tags: algorithm, graph, visualization, graph-algorithm, graph-visualization

I came across following graph layout proposed in the paper [NodeTrix](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/nath/docs/henry_infovis07.pdf) :

[image]

The big blocks that are visible are nodes themselves (A sort of composite node of a sub-graph).

I see that the edges are some sort of curves which seem to not intersect too much among themselves. Also, the nodes and edges don't intersect among themselves. Paper doen't talk about it btw.

I was hoping to implement this visualization. I have following doubts:

Q1. Is this some specific algorithm to arrange Nodes-Edges so that the graph *look good*, as shown in this paper ? Any other algorithm in general ?

Q2. Is there some special algorithm for the curved edges shown above as well ?

It would be great if someone could figure out the exact algorithm in the above figure visually, but some general similar algorithm should also do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One algorithm is [Force-directed graph drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing). It will produce an output very different from the posted picture, but it is quite popular and might give you [a place](http://scholar.google.dk/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&q=Force-directed%20graph%20drawing) to start [looking](http://scholar.google.dk/scholar?q=%20graph%20drawing&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5).

To be honest, I suspect that the shown graph is manually laid out.

**EDIT: Answer to comment**

In the example all nodes are square boxes, and the edges start/end diagonal to the sides of the boxes. A way to to this could be

1. Place boxes using force-direction (or likely some customized version of it, forces depend on the size of the box)
2. Imagine a "guide-edge" going directly between the centers of the boxes
3. Calculate the the places where the guide-edge intersects the boxes, and use that as the start/end points of the real, drawn edge.
4. Make the real edge start diagonal to the sides, and use [bezier curves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) to draw the curve.

You probably want to represent this as some vector format, that has [bezier cures built in, e.g., svg](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCurveCommands).

Comment: Thanks, I went through a few Force-Directed examples and they look good. They however seem to just place the nodes and edges at some distance based on some force etc. Edges are however just straight lines. Any idea about the curved edges shown above ?